# Firefox plugin to save complete rendered page as image

Tags: images, firefox, screenshot

I am looking for a Firefox plugin that meets the following requirements:

- **Saves an image of the complete, rendered page** (not only the current visible [viewport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewport#Computing)) *as it currently appears on the screen and behind scrolling*, including the result of AJAX requests, partially filled in forms, etc.
- Can save to lossless image file formats (PNG would be nice, but anything lossless will do)
- Works at least with Firefox versions 24 - 29 on both 32- and 64-bit Windows and Linux (x86-64); compatibility with other versions and environments is a big plus; Windows support not strictly necessary but very highly desired, Linux support a requirement

Preferably, it:

- Is free of charge; open source would be even better
- Has no native code components or dependencies aside from Firefox itself
- Can be invoked using a shortcut key that does not disturb hover state
- Can be configured to add a non-destructive timestamp and full source URL directly to the stored images, for reference; timestamp format configurability is a plus
- Big plus if it deals well with complex page layouts (think Facebook)

Comment: So, in a nutshell, you want a screenshot plugin with the ability to capture a so-called 'scrolling area', right?

Comment: @nidunc Yeah, that should be pretty much it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### [Nimbus Screen Capture - editable screenshots](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nimbus-screenshot/)

- Has the ability to save the entire page exactly as you see it
  [image: Button menu]
- You can save in JP(E)G, PNG and BMP (or copy to clipboard and paste into any image editor)
  [image]
- Works on all Firefox versions from 4.0. I think it's platform-independent. <sub>*Confirmed, works on Windows and Linux*</sub>
- It's [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis)
- Firefox is the only dependency
- Has shortcut ability that doesn't affect hover state
- It can't automatically burn the mentioned information in the image, but it does have an option to include them in the file name

As the name of the extension suggests, it has a built-in editor.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be able to capture Facebook quite exactly the way I see it (top and bottom of viewport elements appear to be off) and the direct save feature seems broken at the moment, but it does do mostly what I'm after. Thanks; I'm leaving the question open for a while in case someone has another suggestion.

Comment: OK, good to know. It does seem to have problems with content that is fixed to the top, but I don't think Nimbus is the only extension with that problem

Comment: Edited the question to mention complex page layouts using Facebook as an example.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't support Retina (HiDPI) displays. It doesn't capture image at full resolution, only half.

Answer (score 14):

You don't need an addon to do it - while the UI has changed *significantly* since I last used FF and its rolled into a new tool, its still native - you can access it from the toolbar rather than the command console (which seems to no longer be a thing). You can also rightclick and Add it to the address bar.

[image]

<sub>for older versions - see the old revisions</sub>

Comment: And this method doesn't support HiDPI, too :(

Comment: Hmmm. In both Firefox and Chrome Dev Tools consoles, typing the word screenshot gives "ReferenceError: screenshot is not defined", 
Also, Shift-F2 does not open the console for me in either browser.

Comment: I've not run FF in a while - I switched to vivaldi quite a while back, and it has a native screenshot UI. Its not a dev console - its a console for commands in FF. I am told they killed it and you can take a screenshot from the ... in the address bar. I'll update when I get around to setting up a FF install

Answer (score 2):

Screengrab.

- Can take both the whole page or only the portion you see
- Very clean interface
- Can be configured to save images in a folder in 1 click
- Works everywhere

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/screengrab-fix-version/

Answer (score 1):

[**Pearl Crescent Page Saver screenshot tool**](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/pagesaver/) meets your requirements:

> Page Saver lets you capture images of web pages, including Flash content. A web page screenshot can be saved in PNG or JPEG format. Using Page Saver, you can capture an entire page, just the visible portion, or a region that you select.

> Images may be captured using a toolbar button, the browser context menu, or from the command line.

I took the following screenshot with this tool:

[image]

(note that imgur converted the perfect looking PNG to a blurry JPEG image)

Answer (score 1):

Page Saver
https://pearlcrescent.com/products/pagesaver/
(suggested by AL) seems great.

The page also has a link to their replacement (needed if you have the latest FF).
I am in XP (which can only have older FF), but I tried the latest version
https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/pagesaver-we/
So far it is perfect.
TIP for those now saving web pages as images.
Most image viewers are crap at showing large(long) images.
What I am doing is saving such images as .JPEG or .png and I have set the default viewer for those as PicPick's viewer/editor (you can minimize the Ribbon).
I am keeping the default viewer for .jpg images as Faststone Image viewer

Answer (score 0):

Use a [WebToPDF](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/webtopdf/?src=ss) firefox extension.It will take screenshot of whole page.

- print any webpage in to the Image
- Capture Invisible area also.
- print any webpage in to the PDF
- Supports to responsive webpage also
- Create pdf for local html page also
- prompt for saving/open pdf file
- Pure local processing, no Data is sent to other sites over the
  network full Privacy!
- You can generate a PDF or mail for selected plain-text also
- Right Click Context menu support