# Is there a Firefox utility that can convert webpages to PDF?

Tags: pdf, html, firefox

I use Firefox on elementary OS (Linux), and sometimes I use it to print a few webpages or save the print to a PDF file. My problem is that Firefox’ default print adds the page URL at the start and end of every page. I find that quite ugly.

So what I want is a utility that prints the webpage, and has an option to save it as a PDF file.

Here is a screenshot of the default Firefox print:

[image: PDF that shows the URL in the top-right corner]

Comment: I have edited my answer to say how you can use it in FFX.

Comment: Related: [Firefox plugin to save complete rendered page as image](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/4448/1813)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The URL at the top and at the bottom of each PDF page is the default setting,
but that doesn't mean it cannot be changed.

Whenever you want to print a web page as PDF, go to `File` -> `Print` -> `Print to File` (output format as PDF, obviously), then select the `Options` tab, and in the `Header and Footer` section you can choose what to add in the header and footer areas of the page. If you don't want to have anything printed in those areas, just set everything as `--blank--`.

Here is an example with Firefox on Ubuntu:

[image]

Comment: I am flaging this, as this is not software recomendation.

Comment: @switch If the question is asking a software recommendation, but someone gives a workable answer which is not, that's fine on this site. http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/882/are-how-tos-on-topic

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you [Google Cloud Print](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cloud_Print).

It allows you to print documents from anywhere, also saves a PDF version of it in your [Drive (cloud)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Drive). Thus, satisfying both of your needs.

You don't have to download the app or plugin, you can use it's web version here: [Cloud Print](https://www.google.com/cloudprint/).

I suggest you to use the web version because, you use Firefox, which requires some **plugins for this, which I don't recommend**.

Here is an article from lifehacker that you might find useful: [Google Cloud Print: It's Actually Awesome, and Here's How to Set It Up](http://lifehacker.com/5882060/google-cloud-print-its-actually-awesome-and-heres-how-to-set-it-up)

Comment: Does this work on Firefox? It seems to only work on Chrome, while the question asks for something for FF.

Comment: @Undo♦ i have edited it now. Please check

Answer (score 3):

You can use the FireFox add-in [WebToPDF](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/webtopdf/?src=ss) which will generate a PDF from a webpage. Just right click on page and generate PDF for webpage. It will also include any invisible areas.

Comment: This plugin snaps an image of the entire page and embeds the image in a PDF file.  You lose the ability to search and end up with lousy looking text.