# Open source Firefox add-on to take screenshot of whole page

Tags: gratis, open-source, images, firefox, screenshot

I want to take an image of a whole web page, including what is not shown currently on-screen (scrolling).

Absolute requirements:

- MUST BE OPEN SOURCE ([unlike in that other question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4448/firefox-plugin-to-save-complete-rendered-page-as-image)), please provide a link to the source
- Grab the whole page
- Save as PNG
- Works on Linux/Mac/Windows

I prefer an add-on that ONLY grabs the whole page. If I wanted to grab only a selection of the page I would use my OS built-in screenshot tool.

What I have tried:

- I was using Nimbus but they started inserting plugs to unwanted services.
- hitting <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>f2</kbd> for the console then typing in `screenshot /path/to/file --fullpage` takes too much time.
- Abduction! is open source, but not maintained anymore and does not work in current Firefox.

Comment: Many programs won't work for modern websites any more since the websites use those parallax scrolling features in JavaScript. Even the Firefox built-in feature (answer below) does not work on sites like http://www.boy-coy.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox has now a built-in "Take a screenshot" tool in address bar (Click the three dots). It has full page screenshot and visible page screenshot. Can copy to clipboard or download. Pretty convinient!

Comment: Linux Firefox: Available by right-clicking on any web page :-)

Answer (score 10):

You can already do it with Firefox:

1. Press <kbd>F12</kbd>
2. Click on settings
3. Enable full-page screenshot
4. Now you can always click on that camera icon and the screenshot will be saved to your Downloads folder

Answer (score 2):

You can also press <kbd>:</kbd> or <kbd>Shift+F2</kbd> to open the [Graphic Command Line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/GCLI) then type in `screenshot filename` to take a screenshot. To take a whole page, use **`:screenshot filename -fullpage`**.

You can also visit the help page via `help screenshot`. Below is what it shows:

> **Synopsis: screenshot [filename] [--clipboard] [--imgur] [--delay ...] [--dpr ...] [--fullpage] [--selector ...] [--chrome]**
>   Save a PNG image of the entire visible window (optionally after a delay)
>
> Options:
>    **[filename] (string, helpManOptional)**
>    The name of the file (should have a '.png' extension) to which we write the screenshot.
>    **[--clipboard] (boolean, required)**
>    True if you want to copy the screenshot instead of saving it to a file.
>    **[--imgur] (boolean, required)**
>    Use if you want to upload to imgur.com instead of saving to disk
>    **[--delay ...] (number, helpManOptional)**
>    The time to wait (in seconds) before the screenshot is taken
>    **[--dpr ...] (number, helpManOptional)**
>    The device pixel ratio to use when taking the screenshot
>    **[--fullpage] (boolean, required)**
>    True if the screenshot should also include parts of the webpage which are outside the current scrolled bounds.
>    **[--selector ...] (remote, helpManOptional)**
>    A CSS selector for use with document.querySelector which identifies a single element
>
> Advanced Options:
>    **[--chrome] (boolean, required)**
>    True if you want to take the screenshot of the Firefox window rather than the web page's content window.

Note: this only works for Firefox 61-

Answer (score 0):

Use a [WebTOPDF](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/webtopdf/?src=ss) firefox extension its free and and No server processing.
It will take screenshot of whole page.even include which is not shown currently on-screen (scrolling).**This extension is for Windows only**.Its open source.Its using  [HTML2Canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).Its generates a PDF only.Yes i am the owner of it.

Comment: Could you please disclose that you are the author of this extension? Thanks!

Comment: Does it satisfy the "Works on Linux/Mac/Windows" requirement? On Linux I get "Not available for your platform".

Comment: Does it satisfy the "Save as PNG" requirement and the "MUST BE OPEN SOURCE" requirement?

Comment: Yes.This extension is for Windows only.Its open source.Its using HTML2Canvas.Its generates a PDF only.Using Html2Canvas its possible to Save as png also.

Comment: Please include a link to the source code, thanks! Please also describe the steps to take to save as PNG, with screenshots.