# Save complete webpages as Google Document or as local PDF files

Tags: pdf, google-drive

Is there a way to save complete webpage as a printer-friendly (sans advertisement banners, unnecessary elements on the webpage) Google Document or as a local PDF file?

I work on Linux and I am browser agnostic. But this process should be quick and easy --- preferably one click. And it should convert locally --- without help of another website/ service.

Comment: If I search e.g. the Firefox add-ons there are plenty that export to PDF, some even filtering out adds. And you can always combine with AdBlock+ to block ads.

Comment: @JanDoggen Yes. There are. One point, though. Most of them use some external service to convert the page. I was looking forward to an add-on that does it locally. Sorry, this was not mentioned earlier. I have updated the question now.

Comment: [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) (cross-platform) can most likely do that – but I'm not sure concerning the "sans ads" part. Worth a look at least.

Comment: Pandoc (cross-platform) can convert a complete web page, from just the URL, into a number of formats including pdf - operating locally other than fetching the page - again not sure about the no adverts, etc.

Comment: @Izzy I have installed Calibre. But still do not know how to use it with my browser. Could you please provide more information?

Comment: @SteveBarnes I have installed Pandoc. But still do not know how to use it with my browser. Could you please provide more information?

Comment: @deshmukh - Copy the URL from the address bar with Ctrl-C, in a terminal window type `pandoc` paste the url add a name to save to, ending in `.pdf` for pdf and press enter - not one click I know.

Comment: @SteveBarnes Oh! Sure, this is doable. But not one click. Also, not very different from printing to a PDF file,I guess.

On a related note, strange, such an add-on is not available on ANY browser!

Comment: I've never done that, but Calibre has "recipes" for it (and also can be called from command-line). But again, this isn't a "one-click solution" (I wonder if there is any at all, unless shipping as browser addon).

Comment: @Izzy I absolutely do not mind a browser add-on. And I tried quite a few in firefox. But none meet my needs. Most of them use a third-party service for the conversion to pdf which I find strange.

Comment: I have found "Print Friendly" plugin which is 3 clicks, on the icon, on pdf, then download & does remove adds & give sensible names __but__ it uses a remote service.

Comment: @SteveBarnes, I could live with the clicks. But the remote service breaks the deal. The idea that someone somewhere can track all the articles I find worth storing!

Comment: See the question [here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/27937/open-source-firefox-add-on-to-take-screenshot-of-whole-page/31392#31392) It might helpful to you.

Comment: @ManishPatel No. That does not help as it makes the PDF of an image. Plus, there could be text that goes off-screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Firefox addon called Print-Edit that goes closest to what I wanted.

[Here](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/print-edit/) is the link to the add-on.

Answer (score 0):

On Google Chrome if you press Ctrl-P you have the option to print the current page(s) to pdf, (select change destination), and it seems to leave out extraneous, information like navigation bars, ads, etc., *although AdBlock may also be helping,* as you can see from the preview below and you have some additional options like enable/disable headers or background images and simplify page.  I am reasonably sure that there are similar options in Chromium.

[image]

Comment: Yes. Even in Firefox, I can print to a PDF file. But alas, it is not one click. Plus, it is not even intelligent like taking the page title as file name.

Answer (score 0):

use pdf creator to print pdf file from any software

http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator

use firefox addon [printedit](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/print-edit/) to make the web page printer freindly